# pathForResource ofType returns nil

Tags: objective-c, null, nsbundle, mainbundle

here is the code i am working with.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];

if(path == nil)
{
NSLog(@"file not found");
}
```

when i run this it prints file not found in the console.

my file.plist is in the supporting files folder in my cocoa project. where does mainBundle look for files at exactly. this is stumping me quite a bit. i get that it looks for the .app file, but when developing the app where doe mainBundle look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathForResource:ofType:` only looks in the `Resources` folder (and localised folders). If you are placing files into dedicated folders in the bundle then you need to use `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` and supply the directory name.

Comment: I tired using the inDirectory path with the local path to the file inside of my project like so:
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"/Users/joshuablevins/Documents/Xcode/Tutorials/plist tut/plist tut"];
But it still say file not found.

Comment: `inDirectory:` you just pass the folder name in the bundle (supporting files folder name), not a full path. This should be the folder name you set in the copy items build phase

Comment: If you have a full explicit path to a file then it generally isn't in your bundle and you don't use NSBundle to access it

Comment: Should it be a copy files or copy bundle resources build phase?

Comment: Copy files (as it lets you set the folder name to copy into). Copy bundle resources places everything in the `Resources` folder

Comment: And the path is just the "support files" folder name that my file is in or the exact file that is in it?

Comment: The `Resource:` is the file name, `ofType:` is the extension and `inDirectory:` is the folder name from the copy files build phase

Comment: It wont let me select a folder name in the build phase, just the file name. In the build phase the subpath is left blank, the destination is resources, and the item i added was the file.plist.

Comment: You type in the subpath

Comment: I finally got it to work properly. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Good stuff. Please remember to vote up answers that help and tick correct answers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the `NSBundle` you found is what you wanted through :

```
NSBundle *yourTargetBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

or

NSBundle *yourTargetBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
URLForResource:@"YourCustomBundleName" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
```

And get the nil result use function: `pathForResource: ofType:`. Then you can log the `paths` of resource under `yourTargetBundle`:

```
// Given that your resource type is .png and have no sub dir
NSArray *resoursePaths = [yourTargetBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
NSLog(@"resoursePaths == %@",resoursePaths);
```

it will log all the resources path of type `png`. You can get the `image` object use:

```
targetImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"OnePngPathYouChose"];
```

I think the above approach is one way to resolve the `return nil` situation.